# Gnome(Metacity) panel dont show system menu or any other indicators

Tags: gnome, launcher, panel, metacity

I have installed trusty (Ubuntu 14.4) with Gnome-metacity desktop but now, my desktop doesn't show any indicators like volume level, battery status, WiFi etc. Not even a system menu.

Can any one suggest on rectifying this issue?

I have attached the screenshot of my desktop.
[image]